# Read skipped data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I've got an IEnumerable of T. I wish to skip a certain number of T, but in the process, I also wish to read these T. You can read the Ts with Take() and skip them with Skip(), but that would entail multiple enumerations.

I need to read N items, deal with them, and then get all the unread items back as an IEnumerable, in one enumeration.

Edit: I'm trying to feed an IEnumerable to a method that takes a Stream-alike. Namely, I must implement *only* the method

```
public int Read(T[] readBuffer, int offset, int count)
```

The problem is that I need to advance the enumerable past the read data to store the position *and* also read the data to pass back out in the input buffer.

So far I've tried this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipTake<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int num, Action<List<T>> take)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
        var chunk = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++num)
        {
            chunk.Add(enumerator.Current);
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                break;
        }
        take(chunk);
        yield return enumerator.Current;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
```

Not much luck.

Comment: you can't skip AND take when iterating only once, just take both parts

Comment: I think you should make 2 enumarations from this one: one holds all elements except first N, another holds only first N elements. Then, ofc, you'll have to enumerate both

Comment: If you want to skip them but actually not skip them, then simply don't skip them. Can you show a bit of code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @CodeCaster: I have an enumerable<T> which I need to read in chunks. I have a chunking routine but the problem is that the size of each chunk is only known when requested. So I want to get a chunk, do something with it, and then get the remainder to pass on.

Comment: Sounds like you want to treat an IEnumerable like a stack data structure...

Comment: @helb: No, I just need to read it in chunks, where each chunk has a distinct unknown size that you only know when you need to read it.

Comment: Why not write your own IEnumerable<T> extension method which does exactly that?

Comment: @helb: I am working on it. It's not as simple as it first appears. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your implementation does not call `MoveNext()` at the right time. You must call `MoveNext()` **before** you can get the `Current` element:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipTake<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int num, Action<List<T>> take)
{
    var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
    var chunk = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++num)
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            break;
        chunk.Add(enumerator.Current);
    }
    take(chunk);
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return enumerator.Current;
}
```

EDIT: Just to make it clear, here's a usage example:

```
var list = new List<string>() {"This", "is", "an", "example", "!"};
var res = list.SkipTake(2, chunk =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(chunk.Count());
});
Console.WriteLine(res.Count());
```

The output is

> 2 3

and the collections contain

> {"This", "is"}

and

> {"an", "example", "!"}

respectively and the original collection `list` was not modified.

Comment: @puppy wat is the usage